# Calculate centroids of a wings where all the points used to calculate are in the boundary in R

Tags: r, centroid

Recently I've been working in a project relating to detect landmark from an insect's  wing using R language. 
The input data:

```
    X.1    X    Y                     IMAGE ID    Scale isBoundary isLandmark
1     1  193 1053 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
2     2  580 1127 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
3     3 1173 1229 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
4     4 1619 1285 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
5     5 1697 1278 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
6     6 2106 1229 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
7     7 2301 1109 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
8     8 2378 1025 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
9     9 2417  924 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
10   10 2323  832 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
11   11 2168  720 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
12   12 1963  620 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
13   13 1775  558 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
14   14 1734  550 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
15   15 1400  527 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
16   16  618  775 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          1
17   17  295  898 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
18   18   72 1012 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          1          0
19   19  510 1021 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
20   20  520  988 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
21   21  600  961 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
22   22  571  918 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
23   23  584  881 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
24   24  573  841 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
25   25  539  838 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
26   26  547  814 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
27   27  835  906 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          1
28   28  876  941 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          1
29   29  878  978 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          1
30   30  784 1086 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          1
31   31 1224 1041 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          1
32   32 1241  845 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          1
33   33 1419  575 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
34   34 1455  701 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
35   35 1529  935 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
36   36 1560  939 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
37   37 1496 1133 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          1
38   38 1570 1111 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
39   39 1736 1201 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
40   40 1640 1238 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
41   41 1799 1217 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
42   42 1814 1207 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
43   43 2020 1021 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
44   44 1715 1017 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
45   45 1998 1051 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
46   46 2170  931 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
47   47 2041  726 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
48   48 1777  845 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
49   49 2180  836 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
50   50 2333  929 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
51   51 2278 1019 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
52   52 2190  765 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
53   53  215 1010 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
54   54  230  978 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
55   55 1558  566 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_02.tif  4 0.001099          0          0
56   56  273 1129 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
57   57  576 1203 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
58   58  954 1258 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
59   59 1181 1299 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
60   60 1539 1371 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
61   61 1895 1407 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
62   62 2157 1381 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
63   63 2258 1340 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
64   64 2411 1238 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
65   65 2485 1158 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
66   66 2515 1070 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
67   67 2427  992 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
68   68 2280  898 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
69   69 2190  859 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
70   70 2059  808 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
71   71 1846  736 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          1
72   72 1652  710 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
73   73 1286  771 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
74   74  813  939 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
75   75  533 1025 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
76   76  786 1147 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          1          0
77   77  713 1109 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          0
78   78  792 1082 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          0
79   79  756 1041 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          0
80   80  784 1014 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          0
81   81  776  986 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          0
82   82  970 1219 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          1
83   83  972 1201 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          0
84   84  921 1209 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          0
85   85  905 1166 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          0
86   86 1116 1107 F_ST03_07.21.11_LT_03.tif  5 0.001099          0          1
```

The method I use to calculate centroids:

```
centroids <- aggregate(.~ID, data=data, mean, byisBoundary= TRUE)
centroid1 <- centroids[,c("ID","X","Y")]
centroid <- rename(centroid1,c("X"="X-centroid","Y"="Y-centroid"))
data3 <- merge(data1,centroid, by="ID")
```

By that I can get the centroid of each wing following the ID. However, this results from all the points of each wing.

```
  ID        X         Y
1  4 1378.491  941.1091
2  5 1511.562 1100.6042
3  6 1285.222  968.0926
```

How can I calculate the centroid by the average of sum(X) and sum(Y) on those points whose isBoundary = 1 only.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data that illustrate your issue. The data you have included right now only contain a single `ID` and `isBoundary` argument.

Comment: I have edited the input data.